# how to return specific value from a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Im pretty new to javascript and have come accross a problem which im struggling with a bit.

Okay so say i've got the code below:

```
var test = ("{"g":"776","f":"88876","hit":"true","testvalue":"this is the value i want to capture"}");
var capture =
```

What would be the best method for assigning the value after "testvalue": in var test to var capture? I have a feeling i would need to build a for loop to look through the entire string but honestly dont know where to start with constructing it.

Any help much appreciated!

edit: sorry should have explained this a bit better, im capturing this string "{"g":"776","f":"88876","hit":"true","testvalue":"this is the value i want to capture"}" from a cookie and assigning it to a variable. Thats built and is fine, i just need to know how to capture specific values from this string and assign to another variable.

Comment: `test` is not a valid object

Comment: what is `test ` ? this not a `string` neither  an `object`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you putting the `object` inside those parenthesis (`()`). But without putting those parenthesis you can do it like:

```
var test = {"g":"776","f":"88876","hit":"true","testvalue":"this is the value i want to capture"}
var capture = test.testvalue;
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
alert("hello");
var test = {"g":"776","f":"88876","hit":"true","testvalue":"this is the value i want to capture"}
var capture = test.testValue;
alert(capture);
</script>

</body>
</html>
Its Giving undefined

Comment: @NarendraJaggi. Its `testvalue` and not `testValue`. I updated

Comment: wow that was a lot easier than i was expecting! guess im just lucky the data im trying to capture is in that format!